# error while installing pentaho analytics

Tags: pentaho

i can t install pentaho

it shows me this error 
[image]

while i have well configured my env variables 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxIoa.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that a PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME environment variable is set? https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.0/0F0/0P0/020/0A0#Set_Environment_Variables

Comment: actually yes,  that dosen t work cause of my "PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME environment path " was badly configured i will mark it as an answer